# Random variable which is convergent to $0$ but with mean $\infty$

Tags: probability, analysis, stochastic-processes, random-variables, stochastic-calculus

I have problems with understanding the following example:

Suppose $\left( \Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P}\right)=\left([0,1], \mathcal{B}([0,1]) , \lambda|_{[0,1]}\right)$ and the sequence of random variables $\left(f_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ defined by

$f_n(\omega):=
\begin{cases}
    n^2 2^{n+1} \omega, & \omega \in \left[0,\frac{1}{2n}\right],\\
n 2^{n+1}-n^2 2^{n+1} \omega, & \omega \in \left( \frac{1}{2n},\frac{1}{n}\right],\\
    0, & \omega \in \left(\frac{1}{n},1\right].
  \end{cases}$

Then we have $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(\omega)=0$ for all $\omega \in [0,1]$ but $\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E} f_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} 2^{n-1}=\infty$.

**First question:** I don't understand why we have $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(\omega)=0$. Because if we take $\omega=\frac{1}{2n}$ we get $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n\left(\frac{1}{2n} \right)= \lim_{n \to \infty}n 2^{n}=\infty$.

**Second question:** How can I calculate $\mathbb{E} f_n$?

Comment: Perhaps, it is about a.s. convergence.

Comment: If it is about a.s. convergence, what is the null-set $N \subseteq [0,1]$ with $\lambda(N)=0$, for which the sequence is not convergent to $0$?

Comment: $n\rightarrow\infty$ so any fixed $\omega\in(0,1]$ ends up automatically in $(\frac1{n},1]$ if $n$ is large enough, hence $f_n(\omega)=0$. In special case $\omega=0$ this is directly from the definition.

Comment: I suspect the point of the question is to show that sure convergence of a random variable does not imply convergence in mean.

Answer (score 1):

Take any fixed $\omega$ with $0 \lt \omega \le 1$; then for $n \gt \frac{1}{\omega}$ you have $f_n(\omega)=0$, so  $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}  f_n(\omega)=0$.  In addition $f_n(0)=0$ for all $n$.  This means you have pointwise convergence of $f_n$ to $0$ ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables) calls this "sure convergence", and it is also  convergence in probability).

Meanwhile $\displaystyle \mathbb{E}[f_n]=\int_{0}^{1} f_n(\omega) \,d\omega=\int_0^{1/2n} n^2 2^{n+1} \omega \,d\omega+\int_{1/2n}^{1/n} (n 2^{n+1}-n^2 2^{n+1} \omega) \,d\omega $  which I suspect gives an increasing power of $2$ as a result.